# In OR, all the statements checked, or if the first is true, it doesn't check the second?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
//...
let kozvetlenFl = []
if (kozvetlenFl.length === 0 || kozvetlenFl.findIndex(feladat => feladat.id === child) === -1) {
  kozvetlenFl.push(
    feladatok.find(feladat => child === feladat.id)
  )
}
//...
```

What i want to earn with this code is to check if the `kozvetlenFl` is empty (because first, it is), or if it isn't empty, check for duplicate (the child here is not relevant). If i set OR in an if statement, it checks all the statements, or if the first is true, it executes? Because i get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. Because the `kozvetlenFl` first is empty. How to solve this problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Just run the snipped in your question and you'll get your answer.

Comment: Still get the error. Even if i changed the code to:
`if(kozvetlenFl.length === 0 || (kozvetlenFl.length > 0 && kozvetlenFl.findIndex(feladat => feladat.id === child) === -1))`

Comment: The error is caused by the code inside the `if` statement not by the `if` statement's condition. That means that the code after `||` is not evaluated.